# How to use open source iOS libraries without collisions?

Tags: ios, json

I'm writing an iOS library (SDK) and I need JSON decoding support.  There are lots of choices, but the problem is upstream collisions.

If I add, say, JSONKit to my library, and another third party library does the same, then the upstream user who wants to use both my library and the other library will experience a collision.

It would appear then that it's impossible for me to add any third party libraries into my library because of the risk of collisions.  How can I use iOS libraries as dependencies of mine without causing collisions for upstream developers?

Comment: Are you using Git for versioning?

Comment: Our code is currently in a private git repo.  Does that matter?

Comment: To an extent, yes... I'll post an answer with my thoughts on this (we're facing a similar issue as you are).

Comment: Upstream developers have reported that their use of JSONKit causes problems because you end up with duplicate definitions.  I believe these are compile-time errors.

Comment: Do you mean you are supplying headers with a compiled static library and the headers you supply contain definitions also in JSONKit's headers?

Comment: @hooleyhoop I believe he means that developers who import his library could potentially have already imported JSONKit (which isn't uncommon). Hence, there is a collision because you now have two duplicate JSONKits - one in the project and the other in the library.

Comment: @hooleyhoop maybe I don't understand the proper way of including JSONKit into my library - I thought the way it was done was by copying in the .h and .m files.  If so, then it becomes a problem when the upstream developer has already imported their own copy of these files.

Comment: @jimbojw - i get it, yes that is where you have gone wrong, ill have a quick search for a good tutorial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I use iOS libraries as dependencies of mine without causing collisions for upstream developers?

Just specify that that third party library is a dependency of your library, provide appropriate links to the project, and any necessary instructions, version info, etc..

If that package/distro is not well-suited for distribution (e.g. they just have a pile o' source files), then create a public project (fork) which includes a proper static library target.

Comment: +1 for the idea that if it's just a "pile o' source files", fork it and create a proper static library. This can definitely be much quicker than submitting a pull request to the original repo's owner and gives you much greater control over your own end library.

Comment: Accepted because it's the best in the abstract.

Answer (score 1):

We're having this same issue. Here's my thoughts on how to solve it (perhaps we can figure out a robust solution together). For versioning control, we're using Git:

- One option is simply to prefix all classes within your library with your own identifier. In such, even if the class is part of JSONKit, I'd still prefix it with my own identifier ("JG") to get the classname "JGJSONKit.h". In this manner, it's much less likely that a collision would occur.

  This method has the drawback that should a third party repository (such as JSONKit) be updated, however, it's more difficult to pull these changes into our library's version of JSONKit.

  This may be acceptable, however, if this code is intended to be exported as a static library (as you'd still maintain full control over the code, and you'd be able to manually pull changes to third party repositories and rename them appropriately, if you should so choose to do such in future updates of the static library).
- Another option I've considered is using Git submodules. This solution seems to be better should your library be open source (or at least open source to the developers that have access to it -- not necessarily available publicly). In such, developers could choose to simply **not** include any submodule that they were already using within their own project.

Ideas?

**Edit:**

Here's the solution that we came up with:

1) We encapsulated our shared code (which we'd written- not a third party) into a project with a static library target and our shared resources (xibs and images) into a bundle following this tutorial:

https://github.com/jverkoey/iOS-Framework

2) We created a Git repository that included said static library and bundle.

3) We forked all desired third party libraries (so we could make changes to them if desired) and also added the original repos as another remote within each forked repo (so that should changes be made upstream, we could easily pull them into our own fork)

4) We added **-objc** to the "other linker" flags (**important**) so that all categories would  work correctly during runtime.

All in all, the solution is near perfect for us:

We avoid collisions by either hiding the third party libraries (**not** including them in the public headers but private instead), or we warn that those libraries are used within the project for publicly exposed headers and that developers should not add them again (they can use the already included code instead, which is kept up-to-date via the simplicity of including them via said Git submodule method)

I hope this helps your efforts too!

Comment: Prefixing is a start, and it's the approach I'm currently taking.  There are several problems though.  First, it's not sufficient merely to prefix the classes.  You also have to prefix any pre-compile flags (#define JK_* etc).  Also some libraries (JSONKit in particular) use categories to infuse existing NS* classes with additional functionality.  These method additions will also collide if not renamed.  For JSONKit these extra category methods are convenient but technically optional so I've ripped them out entirely.  What I'm hoping for is a solution that doesn't require these hacks.

Comment: How about this: fork the JSONKit repo, make the changes that you need to it, and include it as a submodule within your library? That way, you can still track and pull changes made to master into your own fork, if you want to, and developers using your library could choose to exclude the submodule, if they want to.

Comment: I think that the more and more that you move away from the core JSONKit library though (the more customizations that you do it to), the more beneficial prefixing will become. As your library's code may very well start depending on these changes to JSONKit (and thereby, it's like a new library in itself). Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had a look at JSONKit and i see that it isn't a Static Library, it is a src file to copy into your project.

All Classes, etc. in your project must be prefixed with your (cough) globally unique two letter prefix, including classes you copy and paste off the internet.

You would be better off if JSONKit was a library. Your library would depend on JSONKit, but not contain it, and it would be up to whoever building an app with your library to make sure JSONKit was also included and linked against - no collisions (although distributing a library that is dependent on other third party libraries that aren't yours to distribute is inherently somewhat tricky).

If other people are pasting this JSONKit file into their libraries and then distributing them you have only two options*

Modify JSONKit.h & .m, prefixing all symbols (you must do this with any code you include as source)
or choose something else (NSJSONSerialization?).

This doesn't mean you can't have third party library dependencies (or that doing so is dangerous), just that copying a source file into your project is not the same as adding a library dependency.

**arghh, ok 3.. you could weak link all the symbols from JSONKit and leave it up to the library user to supply JSONKit.m, but then still the problem is the other libraries..*

TLDR.. avoid JSONKit, it isn't suitable to use 'as is' in a library that you want to distribute.